# ignore json within json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am parsing a JSON document using Java Jackson library. I have a situation in which the JSON document can contain a payload field in JSON/yaml/csv format. The parser is throwing exceptions; so I don't want the payload to be parsed. Is there a way I can delimit the payload so that it is considered as a string than structure?

Following is the json document: `{ "recordId":"48", "payLoad":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"} }`

How can I delimit the payload content to be view as a String?

Comment: can u pls post the code how u are parsing json to java?

Comment: *"The parser is throwing exceptions; so I don't want the payload to be parsed"* - this feels like the wrong way to go about it. Why accept broken input? It's no longer a JSON document if Jackson cannot parse it correctly. If payload content can be YAML or CSV, it should be properly escaped.

Comment: stack trace would also be nice.

Comment: If you have control over the other side, have it do `document.payload = jsonToString(document.payload)`.

Comment: Otherwise, it depends on what kind of "invalid JSON" your payload contains. If it is minor incompatibilities between different JSON libraries (i.e. the `{}` braces are still correct), you can try dick out the braces using a stack based approach and escape the `"`s inside. This is less work than writing your own JSON parser, but it is still quite a lot of work.